# Is it possible to send an email programmatically without using any actual email account

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, email

I'm thinking of implementing "Report a bug/Suggestions" option to my game, however I am not quite sure how I could get that working. I do not have my own server or anything, so I can't just send the text that user has written to there.

The only way I came up with is that the client would write a message and I would send it to an email account where I could read them. However, I do not want that users would need to send the reports through their personal accounts. I am not quite sure how I could implement this and googling didn't bring up any good suggestions.

I haven't done a lot of network stuff, so I'd really appreciate it if you could explain ( possibly even in code ) the process step-by-step.

I am using C# and the game is being programmed for Windows Phone 7.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to have some way of getting back in contact with them in case you want more details on what they experienced. It would also be nice to have an avenue to inform them that their issue is being worked on, and if it has been resolved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to do that.  From a relatively low-level perspective, you need to:

1. Resolve the MX (mail-exchanger) server for the e-mail account you want to send to.
2. Open a socket to the MX server.
3. Send the appropriate [SMTP commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp) to cause the e-mail message to be delivered to your recipient account.  You essentially have the freedom to set the "from" address to be any arbitrary thing you want.

SMTP is a very simple/human-friendly protocol, so it's not a massive effort to do all of that by hand.  At the same time, there are [prebuilt libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440730/iphone-smtp-client-library) that will handle all of that for you (except possibly the resolution of the recipient's MX server).

Note that emails sent this way are more likely to be filtered out as spam (generally because the sender's IP/hostname is not going to match whatever domain you put on the outgoing e-mail address you decide to use).

Also note that since you can set the "from" address to anything, you have the option of asking the user if they want to provide their actual contact address, and if they do you can make that the "from" address so that you can actually get back in touch with them if necessary.

Comment: This could work if you have **your own** SMPT server and configure it to allow anyone to send mail. But most public SMTP servers would reject mails sent from a random host. So I don't think this is feasible.

Comment: This definitely does not require operating your own SMTP server.  I use this approach *all the time* with JavaMail to allow e-mail to be sent from dev systems without requiring each developer to setup/run a local SMTP server.  Just lookup the recipient's MX server, pass that to JavaMail as the outgoing SMTP server, and the rest is automatic.  And for the truly paranoid, the likelihood of having a message rejected as spam can be almost completely eliminated by setting the "from" address to something like `user@<current_ip_address>`.

Comment: You would still need to _connect to a SMTP server_ and most, if not all - drop anonymous connections. In addition, unless the recipient is using some really shoddy spam filtering (or has employed white-listing) this will almost always be rejected by spam filters at public email providers, since the sender would not have valid reverse DNS (one of the criteria for SPAM checking). It is a good approach, but not universal.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Most, if not all, SMTP servers drop anonymous *outgoing* connections/relay attempts (and as an aside, configuring any SMTP server to allow anyone to *send* mail is a [bad idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_relay)).  However, in this case *there is no outgoing SMTP server* (the user's device becomes the outgoing mail "server").  Most SMTP servers allow anonymous incoming connections.  It's the basis of the protocol.  Most will do a reverse DNS lookup as part of spam filtering, yes, but very few will reject a message solely on that basis.

Comment: Second link is dead (question deleted).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use email at all. Consider using an error reporting service like [sentry](https://getsentry.com) or [airbrake](https://airbrake.io/pages/home).

These services have clients that you embed in your program; which automatically log your errors, including any debugging information/stacktrace; and notify you by email when your application reports a problem.

Usually you integrate the app's API into your own error handling mechanism. At the point of an error, the client will capture your debugging information, you can popup a modal asking user for information like "what were you doing when this error happened?", save that as part of your error response that is sent back to the service.

Since the app works over HTTP, you don't need any special ports to be open. It is easier and more helpful than having users send you emails with "it doesn't work!!", and you don't have to deal with email sending headaches.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote an article on this: [Sending email with C#](http://comfirm.se/send-email-with-csharp-dotnet/)

You basically have two choices, either you send it using an SMTP-client, this means that you have to have a SMTP-server and be able to connect to port 25 (if you're not using an external SMTP, then you have to manage that by yourself). Or you can use an external email provider, such as:

- [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se/alpha-mail/)
- SendGrid
- Mandrill

If you're using AlphaMail you can send emails in the following way:

```
IEmailService emailService = new AlphaMailEmailService()
    .SetServiceUrl("http://api.amail.io/v1/")
    .SetApiToken("YOUR-ACCOUNT-API-TOKEN-HERE");

var person = new Person()
{
    Id = 1234,
    UserName = "jdoe78",
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    DateOfBirth = 1978
};

var response = emailService.Queue(new EmailMessagePayload()
    .SetProjectId(12345) // ID of AlphaMail project (determines options, template, etc)
    .SetSender(new EmailContact("support@company.com", "from@example.com"))
    .SetReceiver(new EmailContact("Joe E. Receiver", "to@example.org"))
    .SetBodyObject(person) // Any serializable object
);
```

Another thing that differs from just building HTML and sending it with an SMTP-client is that with AlphaMail you have the ability to edit your emails outside your code directly in a GUI. You can also easily create highly dynamic templates using AlphaMail's templating language [Comlang](http://docs.amail.io/?section=comlang&client_env=comlang).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Name:</b> <# payload.FirstName " " payload.LastName #><br>
        <b>Date of Birth:</b> <# payload.DateOfBirth #><br>

        <# if (payload.Id != null) { #>
            <a href="http://company.com/sign-up">Sign Up Free!</a>
        <# } else { #>
            <a href="http://company.com/login?username=<# urlencode(payload.UserName) #>">Sign In</a>
        <# } #>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you manage to include the AlphaMail libraries into a WP7 project since they aren't compiled as a WP7 assembly?

Comment: Link "Sending email with C#" is broken too

Answer (score 0):

So this is my thought, why don't you have the email sent to you...as you?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name"); //Both the email addresses would be yours
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@example.com", "To Name"); //Both the email addresses would be yours
const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
const string subject = "There name or whatever";
const string body = "Errors ect....";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
           {
               Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
               Port = 587,
               EnableSsl = true,
               DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
               UseDefaultCredentials = false,
               Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
           };
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                     {
                         Subject = subject,
                         Body = body
                     })
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

All they would see would be the submit button so they wouldn't have all your personal username/password, also you should prolly set up a dummy account to have them sent to even if it just then forwards them to your real email account.

Comment: I'm not sure there's wisdon in embedding your email password into an application.  It would be way to easy to extract, and it would mean you couldn't change it.

Comment: Solid point. Is it wise? Absolutely not, would it work? Absolutely

Comment: I'd wonder if you've tried to send an email on a windows phone, if a security prompt wouldn't pop up, asking for permissions.  I'd also wonder if you couldn't just include a bit of html code on your app form, in some way with a href="mailto:" and let the phone load up the mail app for your.

Comment: To be quite honest I don't know I have never written anything for windows phone, Im more of an accounting software kinda guy

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this would be to host a WCF Service which takes in your Message and stores in db or /sends email. One downside of this is you'll need a web server to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Try following code this might help you :

```
Dim objCDOMail
Set objCDOMail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
objCDOMail.From = "sender@domain.com" 
objCDOMail.To = "receiver@domain.com" 
objCDOMail.Subject = "Test Mail Script" 
objCDOMail.BodyFormat = 0 
objCDOMail.MailFormat = 0 
objCDOMail.Body = "Testing Mail from Test Script" 
objCDOMail.Importance = 1 
objCDOMail.Send 
Set objCDOMail = Nothing
```

Comment: The question stated that it makes use of C# and not Visual Basic.