# React-native: Send mail from app

Tags: android, ios, email, react-native

there's a way to press a TouchableHighlight component and send a mail? I just want to be able to send it automatically with some standard message.

[Found this](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications) but it opens mail app filling some fields, like if i was writting it to send later.

Do you know a better approach?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234762/send-email-using-react-native-ios/36237525#36237525

Comment: Ya, that's the solution. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Email using React Native iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234762/send-email-using-react-native-ios)